# C++ Non-matching results

Tags: c++

I have a program that calculates(the amount of lethal percentage and the amount of cans) but the problem I have is the output not matching the test file.  I get an output of 
`[30266666, 8647618]` while the test file has `[302667, 864762]` . I am new to c++ and I tried looking into the `int` and `double` but nothing seem to work out.

Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "cs150check.h"

//// Include your own header files here



//// Define any file-wide constants here



/**
 * A government research lab has concluded that an artificial sweetener commonly used in diet soda will cause death in laboratory mice. 
 * A friend of yours is desperate to lose weight but cannot give up soda. 
 * Your friend wants to know how much diet soda it is possible to drink without dying as a result. Write a program to supply the answer.
 *
 * Input: The amount of artificial sweetener need to kill a mouse, the weight of the mouse, and the weight of the dieter.
 * Output: Amount of Lethal and Soda Cans
 *
 * @param cin the standard input stream.
 * @param cout the standard output stream.
 * @return 0 for success.
 */
int run(istream& cin, ostream& cout)
{
    // Weight of the mouse in grams: 15
    //Lethal dose for the mouse(in grams) : 100
    //Desired weight of the dieter(in pounds) : 100
    //Lethal dose in grams, cans is[302667, 864762]
    const double artificial_Sweetener = .01;
    const int WEIGHT_OF_SODA = 350;
    const int pound = 454;

    int numLethalDose;
    int numSodaCan;
    int weightMouse;
    int lethal;
    int desiredWeight;

    cout << "Weight of the mouse in grams: ";
    cin >> weightMouse;
    cout << "Lethal dose for the mouse (in grams): ";
    cin >> lethal;
    cout << "Desired weight of the dieter (in pounds): ";
    cin >> desiredWeight;
    //Math
    numLethalDose = (lethal * (desiredWeight * pound)) / (weightMouse * artificial_Sweetener);
    numSodaCan = (1 / ((WEIGHT_OF_SODA * artificial_Sweetener) / (numLethalDose)));

    cout << "Lethl dose in grams, cans is: " << "[" << numLethalDose << ", " << numSodaCan << "]" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The numbers are off by a factor of `100`, which is the same as `1/artificial_Sweetener`. I suspect that has something to do with it.

Comment: Perhaps you should actually use that `pound` thing, or revise that "in pounds" requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both lines that use a division give me a warning C4244:

> warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'const double' to 'int', possible loss of data

This gives you a hint that you're mixing up integers and floating point data. Quantities like weights and conversion factors should definitely be `double` instead of `int`. Even `numLethalDose` and `numSodaCan` should be `double` in this case, because it could require 4.5 soda cans to kill you, for example.

```
const double artificial_Sweetener = .01;
const double WEIGHT_OF_SODA = 350.0;
const double pound = 454.0;

double numLethalDose;
double numSodaCan;
double weightMouse;
double lethal;
double desiredWeight;
```

Note the use of a decimal zero. Technically it doesn't do anything, but it makes the code much easier to understand.

Despite all that, the result is still `[30266666.667 8647619.048]` with the given input. The conclusion is that your equations themselves are wrong, or that the test file you have is wrong. I'm a bit too tired to figure out the correct math for the given problem.

Edit: The problem really was somewhere in your math. You should figure out the math on paper, then use comments to express what you're doing. Also, use more explicit variable names. It makes it much easier to follow, and it turns out quite simple.

```
// Weight of the mouse in grams: 15
//Lethal dose for the mouse(in grams) : 100
//Desired weight of the dieter(in pounds) : 100
//Lethal dose in grams, cans is[302667, 864762]
// 

const double artificial_Sweetener = .01;
const double WEIGHT_OF_SODA = 350.0;
const double POUND_PER_GRAM = 454.0;

double mouseWeight;
double humanWeight;

double mouseLethalDose;
double humanLethalDose;

double numSodaCan;

cout << "Weight of the mouse in grams: ";
cin >> mouseWeight;
cout << "Lethal dose for the mouse (in grams): ";
cin >> mouseLethalDose;
cout << "Desired weight of the dieter (in pounds): ";
cin >> humanWeight;

// Part 1: Figure out the lethal dose for our human
// 
// mouseLethalDose / mouseWeight = humanLethalDose / humanWeight
// 
// humanLethalDose = humanWeight * (mouseLethalDose / mouseWeight)

humanLethalDose = humanWeight*POUND_PER_GRAM * (mouseLethalDose / mouseWeight);

// Part 2: Figure out how much cans we need to have "humanLethalDose" grams of sweetener

// sweetenerPerCan = artificial_Sweetener * WEIGHT_OF_SODA
// totalSweetener  = numSodaCans * sweetenerPerCan
// numSodaCans     = sweetenerPerCan / totalSweetener

numSodaCan = humanLethalDose / (artificial_Sweetener * WEIGHT_OF_SODA);

printf("[%.3f  %.3f]\n", humanLethalDose, numSodaCan);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have looked at my math and put it in a different way that made more since.  I also look into `#include <iomanip>` and also `cout << fixed << setprecision(0);` which helped with the floating decimals.

Comment: I think the root of the problem was that you divided by `artificialSweetener` in the first line, it doesn't belong there. The ratio of sweetener has no effect on the lethal dose. So dividing by 0.01 effectively multiplied by 100 your output.